# 3D Array in VHDL for Data Buffer

Tags: arrays, 3d, vhdl

My 2D array for this RAM worked perfectly. Now I have the task of dealing with multiple triggers before I read out the data. So now I'm trying to make a data buffer in my RAM, so when multiple triggers fire, it can store the data which can be read out later. I just wondered two things:

1) Is this how you set up 3D arrays? There isn't a vast amount of information on them

2) Is there a better way of making a buffer for my data?

The data is in the format: data[buff_num][word_num][binary]

Each word is 32 bits, there are usually 14 words and I think I've made the buffer 8 bits deep.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ipbus_dpram is
  generic(
    ADDR_WIDTH: natural
    );
  port(
    clk: in std_logic;
    rst: in std_logic;
    rclk: in std_logic;
    we: in std_logic := '0';
    d: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    rdata: out std_logic_vector(ADDR_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    addr: in std_logic_vector(ADDR_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    w_addr: out std_logic(ADDR_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    w_buf_shift: in std_logic;
    en_write: in std_logic;

    );

end ipbus_dpram;

architecture rtl of ipbus_dpram is

  type ram_array is array(7 downto 0, 13 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);    
  shared variable ram: ram_array;
  signal w_shel, r_shel : integer;
  signal sel, wsel: integer;
  signal ack: std_logic;

  signal w_shift: unsigned(7 downto 0);
  signal r_shift: unsigned(7 downto 0);

begin

  sel <= to_integer(unsigned(r_addr(addr_width-1 downto 0)));

  process(clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      rdata <= ram(r_shel, sel);

      if (en_write='1') then
        r_shel <= to_integer(unsigned(r_shift));
        r_shift <= r_shift +1;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  wsel <= to_integer(unsigned(addr));

  process(rclk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(rclk) then

      if we = '1' then
        ram(w_shel, wsel) := d;
      end if;
      if w_buf_shift = '1' then
        w_shel <= to_integer(unsigned(w_shift));
        w_shift <= w_shift + 1;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

end rtl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow... that is a HUGE amount of registers that you are trying to synthesize!  A 3D vector that is 2^8=256 wide by 2^14=16384 long by 32 deep = 134,217,728 registers!  You're gonna need a bigger boat.  Actually you're going to need a boat that does not yet exist.  Maybe some day they will build an FPGA big enough to handle your requirements, but alas that day is not today.

You need to be storing your data more intelligently.  You need to use either off-chip storage such as a DRAM or SRAM or you need to temporarily buffer data using a FIFO.

Comment: Could you explain roughly how I'd use a FIFO in this situation?

Comment: FIFO = First in First Out.  Look up how to create a FIFO using the FPGA fabric that you have, as lattice and xilinx and actel are all slightly different.  You need to have one process who is solely responsible for writing to the FIFO and another that is solely responsible for reading from the FIFO.  I usually put each of these in 2 separate files just to keep things clean.  A couple notes about a FIFO:

1. You must never write to a full FIFO
2. You must never read from an empty FIFO

Good luck!

Comment: So if I have 14*32 bits words going into FIFOs - then can stack these arrays on top of each other?

Comment: I would abandon the idea of arrays completely.  Treat it like a raster image.  You get a stream of data coming in to the FIFO from the top left of the image and reads like a book down to the bottom right.

Comment: RAM should only be used if you need non-sequential access to the data.  If you are reading data out in the same order you put it in, then that means you should be using a FIFO.

Comment: The data always comes in as 14*32 bit words from an external source. I didn't include the explanation of the reason the data is stored as such but this design is actually directly interfaced with a software. So the part where it has "r_data" actually has to be a 32-bit word which is directly lifted off the FPGA. 

I do however deserialise the data first, so perhaps I could create a "raster" then deserialise the chunks I need with the FIFO to be stored in a much smaller RAM for readout?

Comment: AHhhh so in other words I should abondon my 3D array, instead I should have a FIFO => SerDi => RAM => Off-FPGA

Comment: One last question then - Say my data is 256 bits long, 8*32 bit words, can I stream the raw 256 bits into a FIFO, followed by another 256 bits etc.?

So if I have 4 triggers, so 4*256 bits, can I then read out the first 256 bits and then have the second 256 bits shifted along to be read out next, freeing up space in the FIFO?

Comment: As long as you don't overflow your FIFO!  This is important!  The actual implementation of how you move the data around is up to you.

Comment: @Russell  I know this is old, but why would it by 256*16384*32 registers and not just 8*14*32 registers?